# Setting columns order in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have code like this with many columns. The first piece of this code is meant to hard-wire the column order for the final result, as the appended dataframe may have a different order.

```
pd.DataFrame(columns=['foo', 'bar', 'ddd', 'ccc', 'bbb']).append(pd.DataFrame(data))
```

With newer versions of pandas I cannot use `sort` while being backwards compatible to run on e.g. google colab which uses an older version of pandas.

How do I maintain the column order specified above, when appending?

This is *not* a question about this warning which is elsewhere debated in many places:

> FutureWarning: Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned.
>   A future version of pandas will change to not sort by default.
>
> To accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=True'.

It's a question about how to maintain the column order while being backward compatible to older versions of pandas.

Comment: What is `data`? A dictionary?

Comment: Yes. Apologies for not mentioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For backward compatibility, I would suggest a `reindex` step before appending.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['foo', 'bar', 'ddd', 'ccc', 'bbb'])
```

```
df.append(pd.DataFrame(data).reindex(columns=df.columns))
```